# Wercker api call seems to not honour query value being sent

Tags: api, wercker

so, I'm trying to get the latest run initiated by a user, the problem is that I'm not getting back the correct results. 
My API call is this :

```
https://app.wercker.com/api/v3/runs?author=<author>&pipelineId=<pipelineID>
```

when it's just this:

```
https://app.wercker.com/api/v3/runs?pipelineId=<pipelineID>
```

I get back the last 20 runs as expected, but the moment I add an author, no matter what I write (Even random letters), it sends back only results with the same incorrect author (which to respect this author's privacy so will refer to as `ZZZZZZ`).

No matter how I write the author or even use another author (again written in various ways) I still get the same last runs by the same incorrect author `ZZZZZZ`.

Why am I not getting back the correct results I expect? That being the last builds by `<author>` instead of those of author `ZZZZZZ`?

I also want to add I get the same behavior in the browser or libcurl request I'm making, so obviously I'm missing something, I just don't get what.

Comment: We are trying to fix this.  In theory a fix should be coming "soon"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bug where the author value was not being honored.  This has been fixed.

Comment: This was fixed today?